# How to use ML.Net PredictionEnginePool with ONNX model?

Tags: ml.net, onnx

I am trying to use ML.Net to use ONNX models for prediction behind an API. There are documentation around how to use ML.Net & ONNX models with a console app [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-automl-onnx-model-dotnet) however, as it is described in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/how-to-optimize-and-run-ml-net-models-on-scalable-asp-net-core-webapis-or-web-apps/) article, it wouldn't scale well. Since the article, they added *PredictionEnginePool* which solves the scaling problem, but I cannot make it work with ONNX models. When I try to load the model, it throws two exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Repository doesn't contain entry DataLoaderModel\Model.key
Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader.OpenEntry(string dir, string name)
InvalidOperationException: Could not load legacy format model
Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load(Stream stream, out DataViewSchema inputSchema)
```

The legacy format exception is interesting because I tried two different models, one from Azure Machine Learning Service with AutoML, and one with Scikit trained locally so not sure which part is "legacy".

The missing *Model.key* might be the hint though, because the zip model file that is used on the MS API documentation doesn't have a single .onnx file but it has folders with binary files and some of the files are actually named *Model.key*.

My question is:
Has anybody ever used PredictionEnginePool with ONNX models? Is it possible? Or it is not implemented yet? (Not sure if it matters but both are classification models, one SVM and one LightGBM)

---

***UPDATE**

Found a way to do this. So it looks like the Engine Pool only supports models in ML.Net format, however you can open the model as it was described in the console app example and save it in ML.Net format, then you can use it with the engine pool.
There is a similar example for this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/ObjectDetection-Onnx).
The [`OnnxModelConfigurator`](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/0f01ae23a204d142923fb678c5f178b10592674d/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/ObjectDetection-Onnx/OnnxObjectDetection/ML/OnnxModelConfigurator.cs) class opens the ONNX model and saves it in ML.Net format, then in the ctr of [`Startup.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/ObjectDetection-Onnx/OnnxObjectDetectionWeb/Startup.cs) you call the configurator to save the model in the right format, and in the `ConfigureServices()` function you can actually create the pool with the ONNX model.

This works, however by following this approach, the conversion between the formats would be part of the API's source code, so you would need to at least restart the app when you want to use a new model. Which might not be a big deal, if a bit of downtime is ok and even if not, you can avoid it with deployment slots for example. You could also have the conversion as a separate service I guess and then just dump the model file to the API so the pool can detect the new model and use it.

Anyway, thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into your error before, but not using the Pool. If you look at this specific [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5580#issuecomment-759566249) and the comments that follow, we resolved the issue by doing a full clean of his project. In that case, he had upgraded to a new version of ML.NET and didn't clean the project so it was causing issues. I am not sure if this will resolve your issue, but I am one of the engineers who works on ML.NET so if it doesn't please feel free to create an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues) and we can help you resolve it.

Comment: Thanks Michael. 
I think it is not an issue, if anything, it would be a feature request. The pool doesn't work with onnx models at the moment, but there is a work around. I think what was confusing for me is the Ms Docs. There is an example for how to use an Onnx model with ML.Net with a console app, and from that page there is a link to another one for how to deploy it as an API and some might think that it works with Onnx too. 
But it is easy enough to convert the model, so I think there is no issue.